# S3FS failing after attempt to read subdirectory

Tags: amazon-ec2, s3fs

I am trying to mount an S3 bucket into an EC2 server.

To keep things simple, since the bucket has `root` permissions only, I am using the `root` user on the EC2 instance. Running

```
s3fs mybucket ./mybucket/
```

Correctly mounts the bucket, so if I run `ls ./mybucket`
I get all the directories.

The problem arises when I try to list one of the subdirectory with `ls ./mybucket/subdirectory`, and I get the following error:

```
ls: reading directory '.': Software caused connection abort
```

From that moment on, any request will yield the error

```
ls: cannot open directory '.': Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: It looks like s3fs encountered some kind of error.  Could you run it in the foreground with debug logs via `-f -d`?  Also please try with the latest release version 1.85.

Comment: Thanks Andrew but the unpredictability of the tool forced us to abandon the nice idea of having a mounted bucket, switching to a more secure but less sophisticated approach synching at regular time periods :(

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a crash.  I encourage you to run s3fs under gdb and file an issue at https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse so that at least others may benefit.